# How to practise a glockenspiel part without a glockenspiel?

Tags: practice

I've been asked to play one of three glockenspiel parts in a forthcoming performance of a brass band arrangement of **Dance of the Sugar Plum Fairy**. The three parts together form the well-known celesta part.

I'm not a tuned percussion player, and don't have access to a glockenspiel to practise on.

How can I practise my part so that when I get to play an actual glockenspiel it won't be a complete disaster?

Each individual part is a single line (not even two-note chords) but there are some semiquavers which look a bit intimidating at the moment.

Glockenspiel will be of the horizontal orchestral type, rather than a lyre-mounted marching type.

Comment: Have you looked into renting a glockenspiel?

Comment: Second the rental idea.  That is one of the cheaper rentals.

Answer (score 2):

Play it on a piano using one finger of each hand.

Sketch out a rough map if a glockenspiel on a large sheet of paper.   Practice 'playing' it with two teaspoons (or something closer to  glock. beaters if you have them).

It'll be OK.  Don't sweat it!

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal or vertical, static or hand-held?
Big sheet of paper on the kitchen table with a hand-drawn set of rectangles would do for horizontal. For vertical, maybe a sheet of board.

Either will sound just as tuneful ;)

Comment: My grandmother told me that her elementary school taught piano to the whole class at once with printed cardboard keyboards on their desks. She was one of the lucky few that had a real piano at home.  (This was in late-1920s Chicago.)

Answer (score 1):

A glockenspiel has the same layout as a piano keyboard. Allowing you have access to a keyboard of some kind, learn to play the part that way. My suggestion is to learn it both "as a keyboardist" (i.e., play the notes with your fingers) and also by using soft mallets. Actually playing it as a keyboard part will help learn the location and sound of the notes; playing with some kind of soft mallet (perhaps homemade or home-modified) will let you practice the actual movements.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the spacing would be different. I had a similar issue trying to learn parts to be played on a string bass whilst only having access to an electric. I had no issue with the parts themselves, well within my capabilities, just the spacing. My issue was solved on the day - I had enough time to get used to the difference before it became truly important.